Vinyl blind cord keeps going off track from the rolling part attached to locking mechanism

When I pull the cords on my old vinyl blinds to raise it, very often one of the cords keeps falling off track from the roller and gets stuck on its side and part that holds the roller (red box on the photo). The blinds won't go all the way up and stay slanted until I free that stuck cord and pull again.
Is there a way for me to keep the cords stay on track or is it done for?

You can try to always pull in the direction opposite the red box.   The  cracks on the plastic parts shown in the pic says the blinds are very old and probably need replaced.
